# How to make sure incoming quickFix messages have a bounded size?

Tags: c++, quickfix

This is the quickFix code in C++:

`void SocketConnection::readFromSocket() EXCEPT ( SocketRecvFailed )`  calls socket_recv()

`ssize_t socket_recv(socket_handle s, char* buf, size_t length )` calls recv()

Question:

How to make sure that the FIX messages are always < BUFSIZ (for example 8192 bytes)? A message with many groups could be quite big.

Here I am not sure (but would like to learn) that `recv` can always read a complete message?

Comment: Is your question - how can recv() always return a complete FIX message even if it's bigger than the recv() buffer size on the machine? If so (or if not) , please edit your question, it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The QuickFix method `SocketConnection::readFromSocket()` does not just read just bytes from a low level operating system socket. It inspects the byte stream, buffering partial messages until the end-of-message indicator is received.

The '`readFromSocket`' name is perhaps a little misleading from the low level point-of-view.

If you look at one example of the implementation from the QuickFix source of the method:

```
FIX::SocketConnection::readFromSocket() throw (SocketRecvFailed)         
{
      int size = recv( m_socket, m_buffer, sizeof(m_buffer), 0 );
      if( size <= 0 ) throw SocketRecvFailed( size );
      m_parser.addToStream( m_buffer, size );
}
```

You can see where it is injecting the bytes in reads from the socket as variable `m_buffer` into an object called `m_parser` which will in turn notify when a whole message has been received.

This is a very common pattern while serializing information.

QuickFix goes beyond ensuring a complete message, it can validate message contents and negotiate for re-transmissions of corrupted data.